# Find a sum pair in array with duplicates in O(n)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Array with duplicates `[4,4,1]`. Find pairs with sum `5` in `O(n)`.
Expected output `(4,1)` and `(4,1)` and count is `2`.

Approach#1:
Using `HashSet`:

```
public static int twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int c = 0;
    for(int i:numbers){
      if(set.contains(target-i)){
        System.out.println(i+"-"+(target-i));
        c++;
      }
      set.add(i);
    }
     return c; 
    }
```

Output is `1`.

Approach #2 as stated in this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/):

```
private static final int MAX = 100000; 

    static int printpairs(int arr[],int sum)
    {
      int count = 0;
        boolean[] binmap = new boolean[MAX];
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; ++i)
        {
            int temp = sum-arr[i];
            if (temp>=0 && binmap[temp])
            {
                count ++;
            }
            binmap[arr[i]] = true;
        }
      return count;
    }
```

Output `1`.

However the `O(nlog n)` solution is using sorting the array:

```
 public static int findPairs(int [] a, int sum){

    Arrays.sort(a);
    int l = 0;
    int r = a.length -1;
    int count = 0;
    while(l<r){

      if((a[l] + a[r]) == sum){
         count ++;
        System.out.println(a[l] + " "+ a[r]);
        r--;
      }
      else if((a[l] + a[r])>sum ){
        r--; 
      }else{
        l++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

Can we get the solution in `O(n)`?

Comment: What stops you from changing `boolean[]` to `int[]` in approach #2?

Comment: @user3707125 how does changing `boolean[]` to `int[]` make a difference?

Comment: Approach #3 is effectively there. Just use an array sort in O(n) time instead of one in O(nlg(n) time, this of course assuming you can use something like radix or counting sort on your input (which with your given integer ranges, you could).

Comment: I think approach #1 needs filling the HashSet before the for loop, in order to work.

Comment: @egl if you add all number to hash set before hand you will fail this case: [4,1,2] sum = 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your second approach - just change `boolean` to `int`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printPairs(new int[]{3, 3, 3, 3}, 6)); // 6
    System.out.println(printPairs(new int[]{4, 4, 1}, 5)); // 2
    System.out.println(printPairs(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 7)); // 3
    System.out.println(printPairs(new int[]{3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5}, 6)); // 10
}

public static int printPairs(int arr[], int sum) {
    int count = 0;
    int[] quantity = new int[sum];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        int supplement = sum - arr[i];
        if (supplement >= 0) {
            count += quantity[supplement];
        }
        quantity[arr[i]]++; // You may need to check that arr[i] is in bounds
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this also

Map<Integer, List> map = new HashMap<>();
int count = 0;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (map.containsKey(k - arr[i])) {
            count += map.get(k - arr[i]).size();
        }
        List<Integer> test = map.getOrDefault(arr[i], new ArrayList<>());
        test.add(i);
        map.put(arr[i], test);
    }
    
    return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **O(N)** *Time & Space* approach using `HashMap`.

```java
class Solution
{
    static int getPairsCount(int[] arr, int n, int target)
    {
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int pairs=0;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (map.containsKey(target - arr[i]))
            {
                pairs += map.get(target - arr[i]);
                for (int j=1; j<=map.get(target - arr[i]); j++)
                    System.out.print("(" +(target-arr[i])+ "," +arr[i]+ ") ");
            }
            map.put(arr[i] , map.getOrDefault(arr[i],0)+1);
        }
        return pairs;
    }
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int target = 5;
        int [] input = {4, 4, 1};
        System.out.println(getPairsCount(input , input.length , target));
        target = 10;
        input = new int [] {1, 6, 3, 2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 9, 1};
        System.out.println(getPairsCount(input , input.length , target));
    }
}
```

**Output:**
**2** (Pairs)

```
(4,1) (4,1)
```

**13** (Pairs)

```
(5,5) (3,7) (2,8) (6,4) (2,8) (8,2) (8,2) (5,5) (5,5) (1,9) (1,9) (9,1) (9,1)
```